# Copy a Range if a Specific Cell Has Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA but really having fun. What I wanna do is,if cell E15 has a value bigger than 0 program should copy range J15:AL15. Basically it needs to repeat same action for each cell in range E15:E46. If E16 has a value J15:AL16 should be copied and so on.

Below code is what i have so far. It copies only range J15:AL15 even if E16 or E40 has a value. I am seriouslly missing some important point.

```
Sub Copy_Click()

Dim k As Range
Dim j As Range

For Each k In Range("E15:E46")
    Set j = Range("J15:AL15")
    If k > 0 Then
      j.Copy
    End If
Next k

End Sub
```

I feel like something is wrong with variable j but could not find a way to define it.

Comment: `Set j = Range("J15:AL" & k.row)` - you are not varying `j`, it is fixed. Also copy on its own doesn't do anything.

Comment: `Range("J" & k.row &":AL" & k.row).copy`- you don't have a destination

Comment: @SJR its genius, thank you. It works amazing. Currently it copies all rows. Do you think is there a way not to copy if a cell in between is empty? For example E15 and E17 has a value, in this case program copies J15:AL17 although E16 is empty.

Comment: @Davesexcel thanks for your help. In this case this one does not need a destination as destination is rapidly changing.

Comment: Might help if you explain what you are trying to achieve as might be a simpler way. You are copying the same range over again, and I don't understand what you mean by "one does not need a destination".

Comment: @SJR What I meant by "no destination" is, this data will be copied to clipboard only. What you have advised works like a charm. This was my goal and your explanation is much appreciated. But currently, lets say i have following values on following cells; 1 on E15, 0 on E16, 2 on E17. Current program copies J15:AL17. Is there a way to make it copy only J15:AL15 and J17:AL17. As I do not need row across of 0 value.